# Pipe stderr only if a terminal application crashes

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a program which interacts with the user on the terminal.

But if it crashes I'd like to pipe the stderr through another tool to tidy / prettyprint it.

Is there a way to do this?

As far as I can see, the ways of redirecting the stderr all involve doing something with stdout, and that hides / disrupts the interactive terminal.

Comment: Are you asking about the pretty printing, or about how to arrange for that other tool to get the error output, or both?

Comment: What I really want right now is the pretty-printing what comes out on stderr if the interactive program crashes. I thought this would be the general case that would also solve that. But I'm open to other solutions

Comment: Are you able to get the program to do logging to a file, i.e. from the program itself?

Comment: Not simply.

If this can't be done, then it can't be done, and I'll have to look for another solution. Exactly explicitly trying to intercept errors etc. I was just hoping there was some command-line / pipeline magic that could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wrap the program in a small bash script, but it's doable. You can redirect `stderr` to a file while leaving `stdout` to display on the screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Run my program, with stderr saved to a file
my_program 2> /tmp/stderr_output.txt

# If the program returned with anything but success, print stderr
if [ ! $! ]; then
    cat /tmp/stderr_output.txt
fi
```

Instead of just using the `cat` utility, you could use your formatting utility to output the error text.

Comment: `$!` is the PID of the most recent background task, The return status is in `$?`. You can't test for a non-zero integer with `[ ! $? ]` (this tests for an empty string, as with `[ -z $? ]`). It would be better to just use `if ! my_program 2>file; then ...; fi`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. If I do my_program 2> /tmp/errors.txt  that still blocks my interaction on the terminal

Comment: @interstar Prompts etc. (interactive dialog with the user) happens on standard error. Redirecting it to a file would put all of that into the file.

Comment: So basically, can't be done then?